# C# Windows Service - this keyword error

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have the following code which works fine when I use it within a Windows Forms application, however the application I'm writing needs to run as a Windows service, and when I moved my code into the Windows Service template in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, I get the following error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type "MyWindowsService.Main" to "System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeVoke". An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Could anyone shed some light on why I am getting this error, and what I need to do to resolve it?

The code which throws the error is the line below, and it is located within the `OnStart` method of my main class (named `Main.cs`). The code is used to create an instance of the `DataSubscriber` class (AdvancedHMI library).

```
dataSubscribers[dataSubscriberIndex].SynchronizingObject = this;
```

It has to have something to do with the fact that the code is in a Windows service template, because using `this` works perfectly in my forms application running the same code.

**UPDATE**

Correction, I've attempted to cast this to the required type, and now get the following error on run.

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'MyWindowsService.Main' to type 'System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke'.

Code:

```
dataSubscribers[dataSubscriberIndex].SynchronizingObject = (System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke)this;
```

**UPDATE**

I've included the entire contents of the `Main.cs` file from my Windows Service application.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using AdvancedHMIDrivers;
using AdvancedHMIControls;
using MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.Drivers;
using MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace PLCHistoricDataHarvester {
    public partial class Main : ServiceBase {
        private EthernetIPforCLXCom commObject = new EthernetIPforCLXCom();
        private globals globals = new globals();
        private Dictionary<String, String> operationLines = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        private Dictionary<String, String> tags = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        private Collection<DataSubscriber> dataSubscribers = new Collection<DataSubscriber>();
        private int harvesterQueueCount = 0;
        private string harvesterInsertValues = String.Empty;

        public Main() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
            // Initialize our harvester program
            initializeHarvester();

            Console.WriteLine("The program has started");
        }

        protected override void OnStop() {
            // Call code when the service is stopped
            Console.WriteLine("Program has stopped");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void initializeHarvester() {
            // First, we connect to the database using our global connection object
            globals.dbConn.DatabaseName = "operations";

            if (!globals.dbConn.IsConnect()) {
                // TODO: Unable to connect to database.  What do we do?
            }

            // Second, we connect to the database and pull data from the settings table
            globals.initializeSettingsMain();

            // Set IP address of PLC
            commObject.IPAddress = globals.getSettingsMain("Processor_IP");

            // Pull distinct count of our parent tags (Machines ex: Line 1, etc)
            operationLines = globals.getOperationLines();

            // If we have at least 1 operation line defined...we continue
            if (operationLines.Keys.Count > 0) {
                //Now we loop over the operation lines, and pull back the data points
                int dataSubscriberIndex = 0;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> lines in operationLines) {
                    int line_id = int.Parse(lines.Key);
                    string name = lines.Value;
                    tags = globals.getTags(line_id);

                    // If we have at least 1 tag for this operation line, we continue...
                    if (tags.Keys.Count > 0 && tags["tags"].ToString().IndexOf(",") != -1) {
                        // Create our dataSubscriber object
                        dataSubscribers.Add(new DataSubscriber());
                        dataSubscribers[dataSubscriberIndex].SynchronizingObject = (ISynchronizeInvoke)this;
                        dataSubscribers[dataSubscriberIndex].CommComponent = commObject;
                        dataSubscribers[dataSubscriberIndex].PollRate = 1000;
                        dataSubscribers[dataSubscriberIndex].PLCAddressValue = tags["tags"];
                        dataSubscribers[dataSubscriberIndex].DataChanged += new EventHandler<MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.Drivers.Common.PlcComEventArgs>(subscribeCallback);
                        // Increment our dataSubscriberIndex
                        dataSubscriberIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void subscribeCallback(object sender, MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.Drivers.Common.PlcComEventArgs e) {
            // code removed as it is irrelevant 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error tells you an explicit conversion exists, so why not try it? `...SynchronizingObject = (ISynchronizeInvoke)this;`

Comment: @DavidG, yep, brainfart.  I just saw that a minute ago and have already added the cast.  You are 100% correct though, that has resolved the error.  Thanks DavidG.  If you want to post as answer I will mark as correct.

Comment: @DavidG, well that got rid of the error but now when I run the service I get a new error stating it's unable to cast.  See edits.  Thank you for the help though, as that did get rid of the initial error.

Comment: There's nothing else anyone can help you with now without more information. We have no idea what `this` refers to for example.

Comment: @DavidG "this" refers to the Main.cs (main class) of my windows service.  When using the template, it creates a file called Service1.cs, but I renamed mine to Main.cs just because I prefer it that way.  Could it be somehow related to the fact that it's a Windows Service, where my other program is a Forms application and the this works fine.

Comment: And what was `this` in the previous project? There's really not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @DavidG, this in the previous project refered to my main form.  The only difference I see in the structure is in the Windows form application it says "public partial class frmMain : Form" and in the windows Service one it says "public partial class Main : ServiceBase"

Comment: `ServiceBase` doesn't implement the `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface so you can't use it in the same manner. Perhaps you could use `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` instead? Just guessing here as it's been a while since  I did WinForms/Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says this:

> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So add a cast like this:

```
dataSubscribers[dataSubscriberIndex].SynchronizingObject = (ISynchronizeInvoke)this;
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                           //Add this
```

Comment: You answer was the most helpful.  I've found that basically using a Forms control in a Windows Service is just a bad idea.  So I've decided to run my application as a Forms application, and create a Windows service which monitors and ensures my Forms application is always running.  Seems the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a console app, the easiest way to convert it to a windows service is by using [Topshelf](https://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html), a nuget package which lets you run in either console mode or nt service mode.

[Here's the quickstart guide](https://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html).

We use it to write services all the time and it helps you avoid this kind of fragile shenanigans.